# laravel auth policy not working, again

Tags: php, laravel, exception, authorization, policy

Here we go again, everytime I write a new policy it doesn't work for unknown reasons.
I have a voting system where I have a pivot table for votes that references the model and the user along with extra columns ('up_voted', 'down_voted').
My relations are working and if I write this code to test I get it all ok. I set in the DB an example vote for model id = 1 by the user so this code will return 'user voted' while modifying the id to 2,3, 4 whatever it will return 'user didn't vote'.

```
$model_id = 1;

if($user->model_votes->contains('model_id', $model_id)){

   dd('user voted');

 }else{

   dd("user didn't vote");
}
```

so I thought ok I will make a policy for this and this is my policy which I correctly registered in AuthServiceProvider:

```
namespace App\Policies;

use App\Model;
use App\User;

class ModelPolicy
{  
    public function voteModel(User $user, Model $model)
    {  
        if($user->model_votes->contains('model_id', $model->id)){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

so in the controller I have this:

```
 $model = Model::findOrFail($id);

 $this->authorize('voteModel', $model);
```

and of course it doesn't work and always returns an exception no matter what

Comment: What exception you have?

Answer (score 0):

The working code you put contains this condition:

```
$user->model_votes->contains('model_id', $model_id)
```

So I assume that you just have to put the very same condition in your Policy:

```
public function voteModel(User $user, Model $model)
{
    return $user->model_votes->contains('model_id', $model->id);
}
```

Comment: in the working code I only extracted the id to a variable, using $model->id is exactly the same.

Comment: `$model->id` is not what i changed. The relationship name in the working code is `model_votes`, not `model`

Comment: yes, that was an error when I wrote the policy here, I already have model_votes

Comment: Yeah but what exception you have? what fails?